# Custom tags in office web add-in manifest file

Tags: office-js

I need to specify some custom settings for my web add-in. And they need to be specified in the manifest file. Is there any support in the office api to specify custom tags in the office manifest and access them via the Office - api. 
The business use case that I am referring to goes like this. My office web add-in needs to read these settings and then pass them onto a third party Saas application which uses these settings to determine the functionality to be posted to the web add-in. So everytime a customer deploys my web-addin they would need to configure the custom settings before they deploy the manifest. And these settings will determine the functionality exposed by my add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way that an add-in can read or write to its own manifest, and there is no way to have custom tags in the manifest. BTW, the manifest is not deployed to the same place as the web app in the add-in. The manifest is deployed to [AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/) or to a corporate catalog. The web app part of the add-in is hosted on a website.